# Netty server-side RTSP interleaved RTP (decoding and handling)

Tags: java, netty, rtsp, rtp

I am beginner from netty and I need a way to handle RTSP and RTP together as described in the specification from ED-137_4B (Embedded interleaved Binary Data).
I use currently the netty framework version 4.0.24, but I could not find in the higher version like 4.0.34 a support for RTSP for Embedded interleaved binary data, where the RTP is interleaved in the RTSP packages.
I have tried a lot of things, for example I have tried to implemented a second childHandler with RTPServerInitilizer, which should handle the RTP decoding, but this did not work together also with RTSP decoder.
I have also tried to implement of two piplines (see below), but this did also not worked together.

Summarized, when I implement a RTSP decoder and RTP decoder together for example with completely separately initializer for RTSP & RTP or I implement with two separately pipelines, then always only one of the decoders works. For example, if RTSP is set at the first place, then only the RTSP events will decoded and if RTP decoder is on the first place then only the RTP packages will decoded.
If the client disconnect, then I can see that the other decoder will try to decode like as  a queue, but then the message from the clients are not more available. It is possible to handle many different RTSP-Clients over the same TCP-Socket synchrone with “NioServerSocketChannel.class”?

Please, can you give me a tip or could you help me how I can solve to use RTSP and RTP together, because I need it for a project in the new job, it is urently?

Many thanks in advance :-)

Here are my code snippets:

```
//***-->For your interest, functions that begin with HttpServer... handle the RTSP events!<--**//

public class HttpServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{    
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch)  {

     //Handling of RTSP
         ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

       p.addLast(new RtspResponseEncoder());
       p.addFirst(new RtspRequestDecoder()); 

       p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
       p.addLast(new HttpContentCompressor());        
       p.addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());       
       p.addLast(new HttpServerHandler());    


     //Second pipeline for handling of RTP
     ChannelPipeline pp = ch.pipeline();            
     pp.addLast(new RTPDecoder());
     pp.addLast(new RTPHandler());
    }
}


public class HttpServer {

    //static final int PORT = 554;
    public Channel ch = null;

    public void connect(int iPort) throws Exception {

        // Configure the server.
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        //try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             //.childHandler(new RtpServerInitializer())    //Second separately initializer did not worked together with initializer for RTSP
             //.handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.ERROR))
             .childHandler(new HttpServerInitializer());  

            ch = b.bind(iPort).sync().channel();

        /*    ch.closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }*/
    }   
} 


public class HttpServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler <HttpObject> { 

    private HttpRequest m_request;
    /** Buffer that stores the response content for only log output**/
    private final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();


    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
            m_request = (HttpRequest) msg;
        ....
}
...
    }
  }


public class RTPDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

private ByteBuf collector = Unpooled.buffer();

@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out)
        throws Exception {
…
    }
   ...
  }


public class RTPHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteToMessageDecoder> { 

    @Override 
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable e) throws Exception { 

            super.exceptionCaught(ctx, e);            
    } 

    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,  Object msg)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    …
    }
 …
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem as you were (years later), after a decent amount of time I've noticed that you only need a single ChannelPipeline to handle RTSP and RTP packet. Please keep in mind that the order of decodes that added to a ChannelPipe is crucial. You must add RTP decoder first and then RTSP decoder/encoder. Packets that is not RTP interleaved should be forward to the next decoder(in this case is RTSP decoder) by [fireChannelRead](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html#fireChannelRead-java.lang.Object-), you can distinguish RTP interleaved packets by the "$" sign in ASCII according to [RFC 2326 10.12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326.html#page-40). The same exact order should be apply to handlers when added to ChannelPipeline.